# What will happen to Ubuntu 17.04 after January 18?

Tags: 17.04

ZestyZapus has mentioned in it's release notes :

> Ubuntu 17.04 will be supported for 9 months until January 2018. If you
>   need Long Term Support, it is recommended you use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
>   instead.

I have Ubuntu 17.04 installed on my computer.
But I want long term use.
So how can I get Ubuntu 16.04?
Will Ubuntu 17.04 Crash after January 2018? 
Will I lose my data?

I have been using Ubuntu 17.04 for 2 months and I would like to continue using Ubuntu. So how can I downgrade Ubuntu 17.04 to Ubuntu 16.04 to be on a safer side.

Please let me know if there is a need downgrade to Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks.

Comment: When the time comes upgrade to 17.10 and then later to 18.04 and you'll be in a LTS release (supported until 2023). No, 17.04 won't crash after the due date nor will you lose data (not for that reason anyway). At some point it'll no longer get updates, that's all. You have plenty of time to do an online upgrade and if you have backups (you should) then just installing the new version is faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking about doing it backwards by downgrading your OS instead of forwards by upgrading your OS. Upgrading from Ubuntu 17.04 to Ubuntu 17.10 after it is released in October and upgrading from Ubuntu 17.10 to the next LTS release, Ubuntu 18.04, is an easier way to do it. As usual, backup your data before upgrading your OS as insurance against losing your data.

I expect that bad things will gradually happen if you continue to use an Ubuntu release after its End of Life (EOL) date. Ubuntu releases are not meant to be used after the support period has ended. Ubuntu is designed to be a secure and up-to-date operating system and upgraded if necessary to keep it that way.

Comment: Exactly what I said, and almost at the same time :)

Comment: @MichaelBay Not exactly, the difference is 20 points ;)

Comment: Difference @MichaelBay is yours is a comment and the other an answer but of course you can still drop your comments into an answer. Ping me when you do :)